# JavaScript Durandal child viewmodel

Tags: durandal

I am using DurandalJS. My view `welcome.html` has a child view `mymodule`:

```
welcome.html:    
<div>
            <!--ko compose: {model:'viewmodels/mymodule', activate: true}-->
            <!--/ko-->
</div>
```

The `activate` function is called in `mymodule` every time the view `welcome.html` is activated, as expected. But when the `welcome.html` is deactivated (I navigate to another view) the functions `canDeactivate` and `devativate` are not called in mymodule.js.

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using activate:true on the compose binding does not manage the full lifecycle of your view model, only the activate function will be called with that approach. (As you are seeing).

To get the all lifecycle events you need to use an activator to manage the lifecycle of the view model.

You have several options for doing this, see the durandal documentation on the matter for more insight.
http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Hooking-Lifecycle-Callbacks/
Specifically, look at the "Activator Callbacks" section of that page.

It basically boils down to using the router to activate your view models or creating an activator yourself.

Comment: i have edited `ko compose` in `welcome.html` to bind to a property in `welcome.js` which returns `viewModel.activator(new mymodule())`. Still the `canDeactivate` and `deactivate` functions are not called in `mymodule` :(

Comment: Do you mind posting a bit more code, then I can probably tell you how to fix it? Specifically welcome.js and also enough to show how you are navigating to the other view?