# Show a toolbar in shell header that is bound to the current viewmodel in Durandal

Tags: durandal

I'm trying to achieve a context dependent toolbar in the header of my shell. The goal is to have the page-specific toolbar view bound to current viewmodel, not the shell or a separate toolbar vm. (Kinda like @RenderSection in Layout using asp.net Razor syntax).

When the current viewmodel is activated, I trigger a message with an object literal that describes the toolbar view location and that it's viewmodel should be `this`.

```
    function activate() {
        app.trigger('toolbar', { view: 'views/ediToolbar', model: this });
    }
```

The shell correctly listens and updates the activeToolbar binding, but in the process calls the `activate` method on vm creating an infinite loop. Is there a way to prevent the infinite loop or am I going about this completely the wrong way?

shell.js

```
activeToolbar = ko.observable();

function activate() {
    // normal setup stuff
    app.on('toolbar', function(data) {
        activeToolbar(data)
    }
}
```

shell.html

```
<div data-bind="if: activeToolbar" class="toolbar">
    <!-- ko compose: { view: activeToolbar().view, model: activeToolbar().model } -->
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, setting `activate` to `false` is not the solution.  Not really.  The problem lies in your architecture.  We do the same thing.  Our approach is that we simply make the navigation menu a composable part of the *hosted view* (as opposed to the shell).  There's no need to get the shell involved, except to the extent that it either needs to get out of the way or offer up a hosting site for each module's contextual toolbar.

Comment: If there's a simpler way, I'm all for it.  My requirement is that the toolbar must be in header (at least visually). Each module is a singleton and the "toolbar" logic is really part of that module.  I only need to separate the toolbar part visually. You wrote that the shell can "offer up a hosting site for each module's contextual toolbar."  This sounds like what I'm looking for.  Could you be more specific on how to accomplish that? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I should have paid closer attention to the related SO questions in the side bar! [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16060570/384941)  gave me the clue I needed.

In the compose binding set activate to false:

```
<!-- ko compose: { view: activeToolbar().view, model: activeToolbar().model, activate: false } -->
<!-- /ko -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have your viewmodel directly access the toolbar in the activate function and update an observable with itself (With require, the module will be around, so you can just access properties directly on them).  Then from the toolbar, you can bind the view to that observable.

Something like this:

```
function activate()
{
    toolbar.activeViewModel(this);
}
```